# my app showing UITable View as a main page

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using one main xib , Master View and Details View and when I start my app the Master View shows as a main page and I want the main xib to show as a main page .
I think the problem is from the appdelegate.m code

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.viewController = [[MasterView alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterView" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navC  = [[UINavigationController alloc ] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
self.window.rootViewController = navC;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: Your application window's root view controller is a navigation controller whose root view controller, in turn, is an instance of `MasterView` which is loaded from the nib whose name is "MasterView".  Is this not what you intend?  What is the File's Owner class for the "MasterView" nib?

Comment: actually I have a storyboard as main windows and a button when you press it it should takes you to the Master View, but the problem is the Master View loaded as main window

Comment: The `MasterView` is the root view controller of the main window because the code above is performing that task.  If you are using Storyboards using the Master/Detail template for example, and if the code you posted is in the implementation of `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` then you can probably just delete that code.

Comment: you are right, but when I deleted the code form the appdelegate I got a problem on my master View , when I press on any row of my table View it does not move to the Details  View

Comment: btw on my Master View I have a Table view and on my Details View a web View

Comment: If you're having a different issue, I'd post a separate question

Comment: can anyone help please